# How Can I Change Player Components From Different Script In Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change RigidBody2D > Simulated to false from another game object scripts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try looking into GameObject.[GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html). It will allow you to get any component from a given gameobject.

```cs
public Gameobject otherobject; //you can set this in code or inspector
private Rigidbody2D rb;
void Start(){
    rb = otherobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.simulated= false;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But it doesn't work, I think I couldn't explain my issue enough. :(

Comment: Are you setting otherobject to the gameobject with the rigidbody(in inspector)? From what I can tell, you want to access a component's property from a script.